# How to convert a list into a dataframe and filling empty values with NA in r

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I was wondering how to convert a different lenght of List into a user-defined size data frame in R?

The input of the function is L (a list), N(a number).

Input example:

```
L <- list(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15)
N <- 6
```

Then the output should be a dataframe that every 6 elements are filled by column and but the last column may not enough to fill then we use NA to fill it.

Output example:

```
    [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] 1    7    13
[2,] 2    8    14
[3,] 3    9    15
[4,] 4    10   NA
[5,] 5    11   NA
[6,] 6    12   NA
```

If you have any idea how to create this function, I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `matrix` and fill the missing values with `NA` using `rep` and cast it to a `data.frame` like:

```
as.data.frame(matrix(c(L, rep(NA, length(L) %% N)), N))
#  V1 V2 V3
#1  1  7 13
#2  2  8 14
#3  3  9 15
#4  4 10 NA
#5  5 11 NA
#6  6 12 NA
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to count number of columns and then create matrix.

```
L1 <- unlist(L)
N <- 6
M <- ceiling(length(L1)/N)
matrix(L1[1:(N*M)], N)

#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    1    7   13
#[2,]    2    8   14
#[3,]    3    9   15
#[4,]    4   10   NA
#[5,]    5   11   NA
#[6,]    6   12   NA
```

---

If you are ok having `NULL` values instead of `NA` you can save the unlisting step.

```
N <- 6
M <- ceiling(length(L)/N)
matrix(L[1:(N*M)], N)
```